# How to handle up, down & right, left action in game?

Tags: android

I wish to create up,down & right, lift activities in my game.

Eg: i have one ball i want to move right, left and up, down

plZ help me...how to create....

Comment: You mean something like a controller to move the ball and not an activity, right?

Comment: yes i want to control that ball right, left and up, down like touch screen.....

Comment: Far too vague to be answerable. What did you try? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: now i am add one image button in my xml file....next step tell me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it really seems that you don't know a lot about android programming, you should start with a tutorial... try my tutorial serie on 2d graphics... http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html

Comment: thanks now emulator display the image but how to up, down controls we create....this is my doubts

Comment: Read the tutorial (all parts) and you will learn how to interact with the touch events. You need to read to learn!